# C The structure that I have to calculate the number that is repeated the most in an array doesent work

Tags: arrays, c

I'm new to programming and I'm facing this problem. The program is supposed to receive a number from 1 to 11. When you receive all the numbers, you have to compare which number is the most repeated and print the most repeated number. But, the values ​​it prints are not what I expected.

Here is my code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

const int limit=2;

int nro=0;

struct CLIENT
{
    int num;
};

int main()
{
    int nummo[limit];
    const int tam=11;
    int num_rep=0;
    int pos_num=0;
    int c=0,n=0;
    int number=0;
    int num=0;

    struct CLIENT Array[limit];

      for (nro=0;nro<limit;nro++){


do
{
    printf("\n\t number to compare: \n");
    printf("\nopcion: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
}
while (num<1 || num>11);


Array[nro].num=num;

}

    for (n=0; n<tam; n++)
    {
        for(c=0; c<nro; c++)
        {
            number=Array[c].num;
            if (number==n+1)
            {
                nummo[n]=nummo[n]+1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (n=0; n<tam; n++)
    {
        number=nummo[n];
        if (number>num_rep)
        {
            num_rep=number;
            pos_num=n;
        }
    }

    printf("\n \t\t\t\t   ----------- report ---------------\n");
    printf("\n the number most repeated is: %d\n",pos_num);

    return 0;
}
```

this is a code more reproducible, in this I got 8 and the in be 1

this is the error

[image]

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XONU7.png)

This is the expected result:

[image]

problem solved
https://aticleworld.com/c-program-to-find-the-most-popular-element-in-an-array/

Comment: Please post [mcve], your inputs and outputs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: You assign the variable `number`, but then you test `num` in `if (num==n+1)`

Comment: @EugeneSh now is there all the code

Comment: @Barmar thats be a error when i upload the code

Comment: `nro` is `1`, so the loop `for (c = 0; c < nro; c++)` only iterates 1 time.

Comment: @Barmar yes because is a example to how works in the code complete that repeats n times

Comment: @Barmar the problem in the program is if i pass the number "1" thats be a result but my result  is "2" or "9"

Comment: You need to edit the question to explain better what the program is supposed to do.

Comment: Using so many similar variable names makes it really hard to understand the code. `num`, `number`, `nummo`. Use more meaningful names.

Comment: @Barmar sorry my bad to use variable very similar, my question is, "why my program to compare numbers and show the most repeated number doesent work"

Comment: That's the same thing you wrote on the question. If I didn't understand it the first time, I won't understand it now.

Comment: @Barmar the program is suposed to do is  receive a number from 1 to 11, in the complete code it is in a loop until limit, when you have all the numbers you compare which number is repeated the most and shows the most repeated number but the values ​​it shows are not what I expect

Comment: Please EDIT THE QUESTION to add clarifications, don't put it in comments. Add an example showing the expected result.

Comment: @Barmar now is edited

Comment: You only ask for one `num` unless they enter something outside 1-11.

Comment: You need a loop that keeps asking for numbers and puts them in an array. You're just asking for 1 number and putting just that in the array.

Comment: @Barmar now i added a loop to the code